# Gui does not show up on java no matter how simple the code

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I am kinda new on Eclipse and trying to learn Java from youtube tutorials.There was no problem at the beginning. I suddenly realized that my gui related codes doesnt work.There are no errors or any problems.When I clicked run button gui simply does not show up.I might missclick some options buttons because I already updated  jdk and jre.I reinstalled my eclipse.But no matter what, my gui related programs does not work.The worse part is, the programs that used to work are not working either.

```
package tests;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class test extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame test = new JFrame();
        test.setVisible(true);
        test.setSize(100,100);
        test.setResizable(false);
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

not even this simple gui shows up.Thanks for the helps have a good night.

Comment: Your code is a little peculiar, but valid... Do you have two monitors by chance? check the top-left corner of your primary monitor...

Comment: No, I actually study on a laptop so I do not have 2 monitor.I just cant figure out what is wrong.It was working perfectly fine and then it just stop working.

Comment: You shouldn't be manipulating visible swing components directly in the `main` method, only on the event dispatch thread. Try wrapping the code that touches the GUI inside `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to move it onto the EDT.

Comment: Call `setVisible` last, or call `frame.revalidate()` after changing the size. After changing the bounds of a component (size or location), `invalidate()` will be called. You must revalidate afterwards (this applies only to components who are visible)